# UrlFetchApp.fetch aborting execution when trying to get content

Tags: google-apps-script

This script aborts when trying to gather the response content using any of the available methods.

When debugging I can see that executing "getContentText()" causes the script to be aborted.

I have tried mutehttpexceptions and follow redirects. The request is pretty simple and works perfectly out of Google script.

````
  var requestobj = {
    'method' : 'post'
  };

var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.ghostinspector.com/v1/tests/5e20794bebbf452b12be1714/export/selenium-html/?apiKey=xxx", requestobj);


var responseCode = resp.getResponseCode()
if (responseCode === 200) {
  var responseJson = resp.getContentText();
}
```
````

Comment: Where is `getContentText()`? What kind of Google account are you running this in?

Comment: Can you post the response (`resp` variable) you're retrieving? Are you getting and error message? Please post it if so.  For me is working with another URL.

Comment: If you don't use `"muteHttpExceptions":true` in the options, then the code `var responseCode = resp.getResponseCode() if (responseCode === 200) {` will never run if there is an error.  If there is an error in the fetch call, and you don't use `"muteHttpExceptions":true` in the options, then, your code will either halt, or be picked up by a try/catch if you have that in your code somewhere.  So, I'd always use `"muteHttpExceptions":true` in the options.

Comment: 1) The response is an html file 2) the responseCode is 200, so no problem on that side 3) no other errors are thrown, I tried with muteHttpExceptions but since there are no errors, it does not help 4) launching the same request in postman works fine, also with 200 response code and xml in the body.

Comment: Issue can be tracked now here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148240975